# Sort hg status by date

Tags: mercurial

Im looking for a convenient way to sort the ouput of

```
hg status
```

to see the newest file at top.

Comment: `hg status` does not do this so you will have to use shell- and OS-specific functionality.

Comment: I assume you want to sort by file modification time, and don't care about files that have been removed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution that will only work in Linux-like environments (I am trying it in Windows using [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)). You could use `ls` to list files sorted by time, passing it the output of `hg status`:

```
$ hg st
M modified.txt
A added.txt
R removed.txt
? unknown.txt

$ ls -t1 `hg st -n -a -m -u`
unknown.txt
modified.txt
added.txt
```

Using this method you lose the `MAR?...` status, but it shows the files that are changed, added, or are untracked, sorted by modification time.  However, it does kind of rely on your allowed parameters to `ls`.

Effectively you're using the backquoted mercurial command to provide a list of filenames to `ls`, which will do the sorting for you.  Don't think there's a *simple* way to do this in vanilla Windows.  Possibly by using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a file with this content:

```
 changeset = "{files}"
 file = "{file}\n"
```

Let's say you call it sorted.txt and put it in your home directory. Then you can give this command:

```
 hg -q outgoing --style ~/sorted.txt | sort -u
```